# Firebase Data Retrieval node by node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to store values of all nodes with keys in a class but it seems like it isn't storing it in class. Can't figure out the probable correction in the readDataListener(). As you can see I'm trying to store the values of all nodes in a class but don't know what I'm getting wrong.

**SymptomActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class SymptomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
Button button;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_symptom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    // Write a message to the database
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // store app title to 'app_title' node
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").setValue("microDoctor");
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomList");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.child("Headache").child("Some Value").setValue("Head");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.setValue("Headache");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            readDataListener();
        }
    });
}

private void readDataListener() {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("Abdominal Cramps").child("Diarrhea").child("Vomiting").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Symptom symptom = dataSnapshot.getValue(Symptom.class);

            // Check for null
            if (symptom == null) {
                Log.e("Data", "Symptom data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e("Symptom Data", "User data is changed!"+symptom.symptom1);

            // Display newly updated name and email
            textView.setText(symptom.disease);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}}
```

**Symptom.java**

```
public class Symptom {

    public String symptom1;
    public String symptom2;
    public String symptom3;
    public String disease;

    // Default constructor required for calls to
    // DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    public Symptom(){

    }
    public  Symptom(String symptom1, String symptom2, String symptom3, String disease){
        this.symptom1 = symptom1;
        this.symptom2 = symptom2;
        this.symptom3 = symptom3;
        this.disease = disease;
    }
    }
```

**Data Trying to Access**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl3qd.png)

Comment: If want to have the other values under disease?

Comment: Like the nodes in image, I also want to store the names of "Abdominal Cramps", "Diarrhea", and "Vomiting" in class.

Comment: I do not understand. Those are nodes as i see in your screenshot. Show a database structure that you want to achieve.